# Combining For and If loop in R

Tags: r

I wish to merge tables in R only if that variable name exists. For the same, I have made a variable with the various table names that may or may not exist. And then added a "for" and "if" loop to combine the tables. All the tables if they exist, have a common "names" column. The code entered by me is as follows:

```
Designation.Attrition1<- data.frame(names)
x<- c("despivot2020new", "despivot2019new", "despivot2018new", "despivot2017new")
for( i in 1: length(x)){if (exists(x[i])){Designation.Attrition1<- merge(Designation.Attrition1, x[i] , by = "names")}}
```

However, I'm getting the error as "Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column".

One of the reasons for the error, maybe that the merge function fails to consider the element of x as variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x[i]` is still a string and not a dataframe. Try to `get` the data first before merging.

```
for( i in seq_along(x)) {
   if (exists(x[i])) {
    Designation.Attrition1 <- merge(Designation.Attrition1,get(x[i]),by = 'names')
   }
})
```